# How can i drag over multiple or group of selected files from the hard disk  files to a listBox?

Tags: c#

This is the code. What i tried is to mark like 40 files on my hard disk then i dragged them over  to the listBox but it only added one file. And i want to add all the selected files on my hard disk when dragging them , how could i do it ?

```
private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                bool bfound = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                    //add more extensions here
                    if (fi.Extension == ".jpg" || fi.Extension == ".png" || fi.Extension == ".bmp" || fi.Extension == ".emf" || fi.Extension == ".gif" || fi.Extension == ".ico" || fi.Extension == ".tiff"
                           || fi.Extension == ".wmf"  || fi.Extension == ".exif")
                    {
                        bfound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (bfound)
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                else
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

        }
```

Comment: what are the contents of the files array? is there only one file in there or multiple?

Also, what is that break statement doing there, its bad coding to use it but i also assume that is your issue right there. the break will quite the for loop

also it would probably be easier, and less prone to error to use a foreach loop instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

change your code so that first of all you can rid of the break statement, and get everything in the for loop, (change this to a foreach loop for your own convience)

assuming that the files array has multiple entries, you then need to take these and add them as a file info to a file info list, which you can then bind to your dropdownlist

i dont have allot of experience with drag drop events but i think you should handle the drop event instead of the dragover check that here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.aspx

like this:

```
private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
  {
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    bool bfound = false;

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
      FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
      //add more extensions here
      if (fi.Extension == ".jpg" || fi.Extension == ".png" || fi.Extension == ".bmp" || fi.Extension == ".emf" || fi.Extension == ".gif" || fi.Extension == ".ico" || fi.Extension == ".tiff"
             || fi.Extension == ".wmf" || fi.Extension == ".exif")
      {
        bfound = true;
      }

      if (bfound)
      {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
      }
      else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
  }
  else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I needed also to use the event DragDrop and not only DragOver:

```
private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);


                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                  //add more extensions here
                  if (fi.Extension == ".jpg" || fi.Extension == ".png" || fi.Extension == ".bmp")
                  {
                    //do something with the files
                      listBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName);
                  }
                }
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                bool bfound = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                    //add more extensions here
                    if (fi.Extension == ".jpg" || fi.Extension == ".png" || fi.Extension == ".bmp" || fi.Extension == ".emf" || fi.Extension == ".gif" || fi.Extension == ".ico" || fi.Extension == ".tiff"
                           || fi.Extension == ".wmf"  || fi.Extension == ".exif")
                    {
                        bfound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (bfound)
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                else
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

        }
```

This way i can drag one file or a group of files and it will add them.
Thanks.